# trouble using xmlhttp.open on a dreamweaver template

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I have a template on DW that hundreds of pages located in different directories on my site rely on. I've recently added a logout button that does an AJAX request on click.

I have this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../folder1/folder2/something.php?something=something",true);
```

Now when I save the template (update all the pages that are linked to the template), that line of code stays the same for every page, and because not every page is in the same directory as the template, some (most) return a 404 error as the file (`something.php`) could not be found.

Usually, in DW, when I do something like this in CSS (linking a background image for example), DW changes the URL to the appropriate for each page it updates. But that's not the case here.

I cannot go into every page and edit each one, neither can i do a quick find and replace as the code is in a locked region which means i can only edit it on the template.

Any ideas, or alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver does not update paths in JavaScript.

What you can use is a root relative path to your file. Since it seems that ../ is from your template file, I'll assume that your file is located within your site at:

```
{your site root}/folder1/folder2/something.php
```

So if you tried instead:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/folder1/folder2/something.php?something=something",true);
```

Note that I dropped the .., and the path has a leading /. This article may give a little more info: http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=230ad